# TypeError: unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, gridview

I have a JavaScript array which I have converted from JSON object. And, I want to bind this JavaScript array in a GridView. But it shows the error 'unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference'. My code goes like this:

```
 $("#gridview2").empty();

            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

            if (obj.d.length > 0) {

                $("#gridview2").append("<table><tr><th>SLNo</th><th>Date</th><th>Project Id</th><th>Priority</th><th>QA priority</th><th>reported by</th><th>module</th><th>assigned to</th><th>reassigned to</th><th>module</th><th>description</th></tr></table>");
                for (var i = 0; i < obj.d.length; i++) {

                    $("#gridview2").append("<tr><td>" +
                    data.d[i].SLNo + "</td> <td>" +
                    data.d[i].date + "</td> <td>" +

                    data.d[i].projectName + "</td> <td>" +
                    data.d[i].priority + "</td> <td>" +
                    data.d[i].qapriority + "</td> <td>" +
                    data.d[i].reportedby + "</td> <td>" +
                    data.d[i].module + "</td> <td>" +
                    data.d[i].assignedto + "</td> <td>" +
                    data.d[i].reassignedto + "</td> <td>" +
                    data.d[i].status + "</td> <td>" +
                    data.d[i].description + "</td></tr>");
                }                   
            }
```

HTML Gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridview2" CssClass="grid_format">                                
 </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Paste your well-formed JSON string data, it may doesn't have `d` to get it's length.

Comment: sorry for the delay. actually i found my error. But, I really appreciate your effort. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = $.stringify(data);
```

try with this code:

```
 $("#gridview2").empty();
            var obj = $.stringify(data);
            if (obj.d.length > 0) {
                $("#gridview2").append("<table><tr><th>SLNo</th><th>Date</th><th>Project Id</th><th>Priority</th><th>QA priority</th><th>reported by</th><th>module</th><th>assigned to</th><th>reassigned to</th><th>module</th><th>description</th></tr></table>");
                for (var i = 0; i < obj.d.length; i++) {
                    $("#gridview2").append("<tr><td>" +
                    obj.d[i].SLNo + "</td> <td>" +
                    obj.d[i].date + "</td> <td>" +
                    obj.d[i].projectName + "</td> <td>" +
                    obj.d[i].priority + "</td> <td>" +
                    obj.d[i].qapriority + "</td> <td>" +
                    obj.d[i].reportedby + "</td> <td>" +
                    obj.d[i].module + "</td> <td>" +
                    obj.d[i].assignedto + "</td> <td>" +
                    obj.d[i].reassignedto + "</td> <td>" +
                    obj.d[i].status + "</td> <td>" +
                    obj.d[i].description + "</td></tr>");
                }                   
            }
```